# Is a Dex-Based Character viable for a PVP Arena

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, player-vs-player

New question from a comment on [Is this Dex/Int build Viable for a PVP arena playing primarily vs Glass-Cannon Casters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64188/is-this-dex-int-build-viable-for-a-pvp-arena-playing-primarily-vs-glass-cannon-c)

> Dex based characters are, of course, generally no good.

Using a goblin as a base (+4 Dex, -2 Str, -2 Cha), at level 5 I can easily have 19 TAC/AC, and increase from there depending on class/skills.  Assuming a level 5 caster with 18 Dex using a Scorching Ray (1d20+6), this means they'll need to roll at least 13 to hit.

Utilising either ranged weapons, or a Scimitar with the Dancing Dervish feat, why wouldn't a Dex-high char be viable?

Comment: The problem with this question is that you have completely different assumptions to the person who made the comment. The particular restrictions on your arena make a Dex-based character **far** more viable than they would normally be.

Comment: Are the casters allowed to prepare themselves before stepping foot into the arena? High Dexterity will simply help your chances of acting first. The best defense against spellcasters is not letting them cast.