# Ways to relocate/teleport to improve a ranged fighter mobility

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, teleportation

The Stealth rules seems to be kind of a sore point in DnD/Pathfinder systems.  What I'm getting at requires two separate questions I haven't been able to find an answer to:

I'm mostly a Dex characters player, and thus have experimented with a few builds (mainly Rogues. Strange, I know), one of which was a Sniper inspired from [this thread.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64188/is-this-dex-int-build-viable-for-a-pvp-arena-playing-primarily-vs-glass-cannon-c)  Its major draws are that Stealth protects you effectively from most attack (most Dex builds I've made being squishy but having insane Reflex saves to escape AoE) and allows a Rogue to Sneak Attack and deal massive amounts of damage.

I couldn't locate the rule about the enchanted weapon used there, so I settled for a crouched crossbow and a bunch of feats to alleviate the -20 to Stealth check after firing.

- The main drawback to this approach is that it's really hard to hide
  again once you've been spotted, and things tend to get ugly when a
  close range character manages to reach your vincinity (Hello, big
  mean DR regenerating barbarian wielding a huge axe).
- The fact that you need to be lying down to reduce the Stealth penalty
  means you need to get up before beginning to run, causing mobility
  problem. And the build requires a crossbow or a firearm - the former
  being incredibly inferior to longbow and the latter rarely allowed.

I was looking into interactions between Shadowdancers and Rogue Snipers for obvious reasons: the Shadowdancers have the *Hide in Plain Sight* feat, which allows you to make a Stealth check once you've been spotted (and strangely does not indicate any kind of malus to your check regarding the fact you're in sight) and the *Shadow Jump*, for quick relocation/escape.

A teleporting sneaky sniper seems an interesting prospect, but I have two questions ([other one here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138624/does-relocation-teleportation-while-hidden-requires-a-new-stealth-check)):

The Shadow Jump ability works as the *Dimension Door* spell. It is, as far as I understand, a relocation at the cost of a standard action which does not allow any further action this turn.

**Is there any combination of feats/class feature that would allow someone to relocate with a lesser cost of actions and allows attack on the same turn?** (Preferably while keeping Stealth - using *only Paizo materials*).

Comment: RE: "I couldn't locate the rule about the enchanted weapon used there." Those answers are big, and I'd like to help. What rule exactly?

Comment: Okay, I feel pretty dumb now. I've been rereading the answer, and understood what I got wrong the first time. The recommended weapon is a Longbow enchanted with Cloud of Fog. First time I read, I assumed it was a Store Spell enchantment, but since it empty once the spell is used, you can't cycle with it during the fight, unless you spend a turn to cast it again yourself. But Cloud of Fog having a ten minutes duration, I suppose the answer doesn't expects you cycle with it.
But if you want to be self sufficient, you might as well cast it yourself and chose the moment it occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Dimensional Agility line of Feats does most of what you want.

[Dimensional Agility](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-agility) allows you to perform other actions after teleporting, but leaves it as a Standard action (level 9).
[Dimensional Assault](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-assault) allows you to perform an attack appropriate to a *charge* while teleporting. (level 11)
[Dimensional Dervish](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-dervish/) finally allows you to perform a Full Attack as part of your teleport. (level 13)

And these others that are not for the ranged build referenced in your other questions, but worth mentioning:
[Dimensional Savant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-savant/) allows your teleportation to provide Flanking, including with yourself.
[Dimensional Maneuvers](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-maneuvers/) provides +4 on Combat Maneuvers used while activating Dimensional Assault/Dervish.

Unfortunately, Shadow Jump doesn't qualify for these unless you first take the [Flexible Shadow Jump](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/flexible-shadow-jump/) feat as well. Monks with Abundant Step can make excellent use of Dimensional Dervish and ranged attacks, especially if your GM allows the Zen Archer archetype. Eldritch Knights and Arcane Tricksters with the actual Dimension Door spell are the easiest to benefit from these.